# Table styling with jquery - Jquery event styling not responding accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a table with about 15 tr's and 11 td's for each tr. I which a could on hovering the tr to make only the td number 8 (from 0) to be styled through the .css() method.

Problem: with my code it selects the whole column , all the td's with the .media class , not only the one in the hovered tr.

EDIT :

**Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/XgH43/3/**

CHANGED :
Here is what I tried:

note: MEDIA, LIGADO and HIDE are reference to classes I made.
 note 2 : I don't have access to the css or the php, I'm working separated from them, later they can implement classes and whatever they feel like it.

```
//MOUSE OVER:

    //MEDIA W/O .LIGADO:

    //W/O .HIDE:
    $("tr.destacar:not(.hide, .ligado)").mouseover(function (){
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        : 'purple',
        'box-shadow'        : 'inset 0 10px 20px 5px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   : 'inset 0 10px 20px 5px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 0 10px 20px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        'text-decoration'   : 'underline'
    }
    );
    }
);

    //WITH HIDE:  
    $("tr.destacar.hide:not(.ligado)").mouseover(function (){
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        : 'green',
        'box-shadow'        : 'inset 0 10px 20px 5px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   : 'inset 0 10px 20px 5px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': 'inset 0 10px 20px #FFFFFF,0 1px 5px #929292',
        'text-decoration'   : 'underline'
    }
    );
    }
);

//MOUSE OUT:

    //MEDIA W/O .LIGADO:

    //MEDIA W/O.HIDE:
    $(".destacar").not(".hide, .ligado").mouseout(function (){
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        : 'red',
        'box-shadow'        : 'none',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   : 'none',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none',
        'text-decoration'   : 'none'
    }
    );
    }
    );

    //MEDIA WITH .HIDE:
$(".destacar.hide").not(".ligado").mouseout(function (){    
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        : 'yellow',
        'box-shadow'        : 'none',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   : 'none',
        '-webkit-box-shadow': 'none',
        'text-decoration'   : 'none'
    }
    ); 
}
);

// ON CLICK:
// 
    //MEDIA WITH LIGADO:

    $('.destacar.ligado').not(".hide").click(function () {

    //MEDIA W/O HIDE:
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        :'red',
        'box-shadow'        :'none',
        'font-weight'       :'normal',
        'font-size'         :'default',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   :'none',
        'box-shadow'        :'none',
        '-webkit-box-shadow':'none',
        '-o-box-shadow'     :'none'
    }
    );
}
);

    //MEDIA WITH .HIDE:
    $('.destacar.hide.ligado').click(function () {
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        :'yellow',
        'box-shadow'        :'none',
        'font-weight'       :'normal',
        'font-size'         :'default',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   :'none',
        'box-shadow'        :'none',
        '-webkit-box-shadow':'none',
        '-o-box-shadow'     :'none'
    }
    );
}
);

    //MEDIA W/O .LIGADO

    //MEDIA W/O .HIDE:
    $('.destacar').not(".hide, .ligado").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass(".ligado");
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        :'purple',
        'box-shadow'        :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        'font-weight'       :'bolder',
        'font-size'         :'12pt',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        'box-shadow'        :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        '-webkit-box-shadow':'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        '-o-box-shadow'     :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775'
    }
    );
    }
    );

    //MEDIA WITH .HIDE:
    $('.destacar.hide').not(".ligado").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass(".ligado");
    $("td.media", $(this)).css(
    {
        'background'        :'green',
        'box-shadow'        :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        'font-weight'       :'bolder',
        'font-size'         :'12pt',
        '-moz-box-shadow'   :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        'box-shadow'        :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        '-webkit-box-shadow':'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775',
        '-o-box-shadow'     :'0 1px 5px #FFFFFF,inset 0 10px 20px #305775'
    }
    );
    }
    );
```

It's not the full code , but It's the part that matters. I've changed it and now it almost works, but still not fully working.
PS.: It's the tr that must not have the .hide and .ligado classes and not the td.

Jsfiddle  full version code : **http://jsfiddle.net/XgH43/3/**

Comment: can u paste u r html code here or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: also you can make this better by putting the css in a style sheet as a class, then simply ise .addClass() and .removeClass() on .hover() or .live(), makes your js cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've acctually used the tow previous answers - if you know how could I reward both the authors please tell me - and came up with the solution , but unfortunetly I had to edit the css file , which fails my goal to not do so, I could mess arround and find another solution , but really , to edit the css makes it much cleaner.
Here it is the jsfiddle link of it (by the way , the colors are just for testing , I wouldn't make it so ugly).
Thanks again , Niclas and Sheikh.

Comment: Glad to know that and +1 on question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your selectors from the style

```
$(this + ":not(.hide, .ligado) td.media")
```

to

```
$(":not(.hide, .ligado) td.media", this)
```

This will limit the selection to the element which has the mouseover.

Comment: Ok , that's great to've learned, but it completely erased my box-shadow effect from the view.

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro Could you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example? Or atleast provide the HTML?

Comment: @GiovanniDiToro Well, my first suggestion is to use CSS classes that you add and remove from the elements. That will drastically reduce the amount of code and make it easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td.media', $(this)).not('.hide, .ligado').css({...});
```

**Update** (From your comment I realized that it should be)

```
$("tr.destacar").not('.hide, .ligado').mouseover(function(){
    $('td.media', $(this)).css({...});
});
```

Comment: It's the tr that must not have the .hide and .ligado classes and not the td. I haven't tested it yet but I'm just complementing my post. I'll get back to you on this , thank you.

Comment: I've updated my code and added the jsfiddle of the whole thing. I nailed the mouse over and out , but the click part is killing me , I can't see where it's wrong.